# Taking single sheet Google spreadsheet, making it into a pdf and placing it in Drive

Tags: google-apps-script

I've been hours at this trying every which way and any kind of function that might result in something and I'm getting nowhere and frustrated.  The code (stripped to the bare essentials):

```
function alone() {
    try {
      spreadSheetFile = DocsList.getFileById("KEY FOR A GOOGLE SPREADSHEET").getAs('application/pdf');
    }
    catch (e) {
      Logger.log ("Catched something: "+e+"\n"+e.stack);
    }
      createFile('test file', content, 'application/pdf');
}
```

Getting the dreaded "Unexpected exception upon serializing continuation" and not even going to the catch, so nothing logged.  I've used various methods tagged onto the end of "getAs", getBlob(), just about everything.  I'm guessing this is just another part of Google code that's nogga, nogga,  noggonna work here anymore.

Comment: Just started happening to me in a function that has worked fine for a month. I'm using `createFile(file.getAs('application/pdf'))`, and now it generates this same error.

Comment: I should mention I could get it to create a file using getBytes() but the file always gave an error when attempting to open in Google Drive

Comment: Just when I was giving up hope I looked in a different direction and found this which works:

Comment: found this which works, will need to post in parts:
KEY = "SS KEY";
baseFolderObject = DocsList.getFolderById("FOLDER KEY");

function getStarted() {
  var contentfile = spreadsheetToPDF(KEY);
  baseFolderObject.createFile(contentfile);
}

Comment: function spreadsheetToPDF(key) {
 
  var oauthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService("spreadsheets");
  var scope = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds"
 
  oauthConfig.setConsumerKey("anonymous");
  oauthConfig.setConsumerSecret("anonymous");
  oauthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope="+scope);
  oauthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://accounts.google.com/OAuthAuthorizeToken");    
  oauthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");

Comment: var requestData = {
    "oAuthServiceName": "spreadsheets",
    "oAuthUseToken": "always",
  };
 
  var name = DocsList.getFileById(key).getName()+".pdf";
 
  var pdf = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key="+key+"&exportFormat=pdf&gid=2777&gridlines=0&printtitle=0&size=7&fzr=true&portrait=1&fitw=1", requestData).getBlob().setName(name);
 
  return pdf;
}

You'll have to okay the permissions first time around

Answer (score 0):

your syntax is simply wrong...
try like this and it will work : *(the sheet in this example has a single cell with value "empty sheet" and is shared)*

```
function alone() {
try { 
 var spreadSheetFile = DocsList.getFileById("0AjUO-g3TOXkodHNtUUxwMEY5UHNCaTE3TDZLSmgweWc")
 var pdf = spreadSheetFile.getAs('application/pdf'); 
} catch (e) {
  Logger.log ("Catched something: "+e+"\n"+e.stack);
}
 DocsList.createFile(pdf)
}
```