# Is it possible in a Google Apps Script to Export to PDF several specific Sheets?

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, spreadsheet

So far based on what I know about Google Apps Script it's possible to export all sheets of a spreadsheet via script:

```
GOOGLE_URL_FEED + SSID + "&portrait=true&portrait=true&fitw=true&fzr=true&gridlines=0&exportFormat=pdf";
```

Or only single sheet via script

```
GOOGLE_URL_FEED + SSID + "&gid=74&portrait=true&portrait=true&fitw=true&fzr=true&gridlines=0&exportFormat=pdf";
```

Is it possible if a I have a Spreadsheet with say 5 sheets to export to PDF via script just 3 of them or pick exactly which ones I want to export?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16469207/taking-single-sheet-google-spreadsheet-making-it-into-a-pdf-and-placing-it-in-d), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451360/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-pdf-with-google-apps-script-that-includes-only-a-spec).

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure there isnt a way by building an export url.
However you could make a copy of fhe spreadsheet, delete unwanted sheets, export, and delete that temp spreadsheet. Will add a few seconds extra but will work.